# Haproxy using stick-table and url parameters for flash?

Tags: haproxy

I have the following configuration:

```
backend webservers_backend
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
stick-table type string len 40 size 20k
stick store-response set-cookie(SERVERID) table webservers_backend
stick on url_param(SERVERID) table webservers_backend
server memtom1 ip1 check inter 5000 cookie memtom1
server memtom2 ip2 check inter 5000 cookie memtom2
```

however it does not work when using url parameters only when i use cookies, however, flash does not support cookies.The call from flash(getConfig?val1=xcv93ec9&SERVERID=memtom2;%20path=/) i also try(getConfig?val1=xcv93ec9&SERVERID=memtom2)

Comment: HAProxy can't store in a stick table headers it has
itself setup.
So the line
  stick store-response set-cookie(SERVERID) table webservers_backend
will work only if the server set-up the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy can't store in a stick table headers it has
itself setup.
So the line
  stick store-response set-cookie(SERVERID) table webservers_backend
will work only if the server set-up the cookie.